# What are good options in 2017 for static web site generators/managers

Tags: node.js, wordpress, content-management-system, static-content

I am starting a new project and am trying to think about how to keep the need for content servers for non-dynamic resources (articles, API info, etc) to a minimum... to that end I'd like to (possibly) use static web content wherever possible rather than have live web servers (nodejs, Wordpress,etc) and serve things up from S3 and CloudFront (or similar CDNs).

Looking over the obvious static generators like Hugo, Pelican, Jekyll, etc I see that in terms of activity they are all pretty inactive from a Github perspective.

Anyone have any suggestions about new tools I should look at, or if the current ones are all more or less equal,  how well do they scale in terms of managing larger content collections?  Or will, if my needs get big enough, will I basically have to capitulate an go back to more a more server-centric solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a closer look at Statamic:
https://statamic.com

It's a CMS without a DB and allows you to output a static html page:
https://docs.statamic.com/caching